# Are general questions formed in plural or in singular?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

When asking a general question about something in English, should they be formed in plural or in singular? Or rather what is a good way of forming it?

> How *are articles* used in English?

Or

> How *is an article* used in English?

Comment: Are you using the word *article* to mean grammatical articles (a, an, the) or are you meaning "a generic thing" and the question could apply to verbs or adjectives, or pens, or telephones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatical ways of making a generic reference. (It is, incidentally, a strange question. Proverbs do not usually have any particular construction.)

**EDIT**:
The same applies to your edited post. A third way in that particular case is to use the definite article: *How is the article used in English?* although some might object to that on the grounds that English has more than one article.